# Covering lemmas and Differentiation Theory

Tags: analysis, soft-question

On an intuitive level, why do differentiation theorems often make use of covering lemmas?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting question, but for those of us who are not conversant in the details of these proofs, could you give some examples?

Comment: What is a cover lemma?

Comment: @RyanReich A source that immediately comes to mind is Stein and Shakarchi's *Real Analysis*, chapter 3 (volume 3 of the Princeton Lectures in Analysis series). A weak-type inequality for the maximal function is proven using a covering lemma, and I think other results about differentiation are too.

Comment: @RyanReich One might also wonder about the Calderón-Zygmund lemma, which is crucial for doing harmonic analysis.